# Puppeteer + Docker + Cloud Run

Tags: node.js, docker, google-chrome, puppeteer, google-cloud-run

i've been struggling with this for a couple of days now...

I have nestjs backend which use puppeteer to scrap a few websites and want to run it on cloud run, the docker is up and running but when trying to launch the browser 'puppeteer.launch' it gives me an error

```
error: TimeoutError: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for the WS endpoint URL to appear in stdout!
at ChromeLauncher.launch (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ProductLauncher.js:145:23)
at async PuppeteerExtra.launch (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-extra/dist/index.cjs.js:128:25)
```

My docker file

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:lts-alpine

ENV PORT 3000
ENV HOST 0.0.0.0

USER root

WORKDIR /app

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache nmap && \
  echo @edge http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
  echo @edge http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
  apk update && \
  apk add --no-cache \
  chromium \
  harfbuzz \
  "freetype>2.8" \
  ttf-freefont \
  nss

RUN apk add shadow && \
  usermod --unlock root


COPY . .

RUN npm install
RUN npx prisma generate
RUN npm run build

RUN groupadd -r pptruser && useradd -r -g pptruser -G audio,video pptruser \
  && mkdir -p /home/pptruser/Downloads \
  && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /home/pptruser \
  && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /app/node_modules \
  && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /app/package.json \
  && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /app/package-lock.json

USER pptruser

ENV NODE_ENV=production

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
```

Im using chromium, prisma for database and alpine. been trying a lot of different setups installing google chrome, using puppeteer container image and always end up in the same error, timed out 30000, the timed out its when the browser launch

My puppeteer launch

```
this.#browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: 'new',
      executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser',
      args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--disable-gpu'],
    });
```

another variation i've been trying

```
    this.#browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser',
      args: ['--use-gl=egl'],
    });
```

tried without args too, same error given

The error shows on the cloud run logs

When i try to run the scrapper on the docker locally it gives me this other error

```
  error: Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
  qemu: uncaught target signal 5 (Trace/breakpoint trap) - core dumped
  qemu: uncaught target signal 5 (Trace/breakpoint trap) - core dumped
  [64:97:0426/155257.980443:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
  [0426/155258.096106:ERROR:scoped_ptrace_attach.cc(27)] ptrace: Function not implemented (38)
  Assertion failed: p_rcu_reader->depth != 0 (/qemu/include/qemu/rcu.h: rcu_read_unlock: 101)
```

Which apparently its because of the M1 Mac

[Cloud run logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6Uqf.png)

Comment: Have you installed `chromium-browser` with `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`?

Comment: @Jordy Yes, i've tried that too, i'm installing everything on my windows machine now to test everything there

Comment: @Jordy its working perfectly on my windows machine, seems to be a problem with cloud run

Comment: Have you tried using the 2nd generation execution environment? https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/execution-environments

Comment: @BenK Just tried that, added a picture of the cloud run logs, still the same error

Comment: @yRipper I think you should import `chromium-browser` in `Dockerfile` because you are running the browser inside docker environment.